# Show that there exists a unique topology $\tau$ on $X$ such that $\mathcal{A} \subset \tau$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathscr{P}(X)$ be a family of subsets of $X$. Show that there exists a unique topology $\tau$ on $X$ such that $\mathcal{A} \subset \tau$.

This is the same as showing that the topology generated by the subbase $\mathcal{A}$ is the coarsest topology we can put on $X$?

I don't know how to show that $$\mathcal{B}=\{B_1\cap B_2 \cap \dots \cap B_n \mid B_i \in \mathcal{A}\}$$ forms a basis for $X$. I think I need to assume that $X$ can be gotten from some of the intersections in order for this to work? If so, then $\forall x \in X : \exists B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B$. Also if $U, V \in \mathcal{B}$, then $U = \bigcap_{k \in \Bbb N}B_k$ and $V=\bigcap_{j \in \Bbb N}B_j$ so $U \cap V$ is either empty or the smaller one of $U$ or $V$, but in both cases in $\mathcal{B}$?

Now elements of $\tau$ are arbitary unions and finite intersection of $\mathcal{B}$ how can I show that this is the coarsest topology I can put on $X$?

Comment: As the question is stated right now, this looks false. For example, what is $\mathcal{A}$ is already a topology? Then there might be bigger topologies which contain it. So a topology which contains $\mathcal{A}$ might not be unique.

Comment: @Mark the problem is from introduction to topology by Gamelin & Greene. Problem 5 of chapter on bases.

Comment: @Lakritsa Are you sure you have copied it correctly? The current statement you have at the top is certainly false.

Comment: I found the book online. You have left out one key word from the exercise. It should say "unique smallest topology."

Comment: Yes, just take $\mathcal{A}$ as a subbase or $\mathcal{A} \cup \{X\}$ if you're following Munkres' conventions. Unicity is a small argument.

Answer (score 1):

This topology can be defined as $\tau = \bigcap \{ \tau'\mid \tau' \text{ a topology on } X: \mathcal{A} \subseteq \tau' \}$

The collection over which we take the intersection is non-empty as the discrete topology $\tau'=\mathscr{P}(X)$ is always in it, and an intersection of topologies is again a topology. Minimality is obvious. We just use that the set of topologies on $X$ is a complete lattice.

A simple argument will show $\tau$ is unique as well.